# Creating a shadow view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I have a UIView set as "shadow", and I put this view behind a UIImageView to create a shadow effect. The only problem is, if you decrease the alpha of the image, you can see the white part of the UIView. How do I hide the whole UIView except for the shadow? Setting the backgroundColor to clearColor hides both the view and the shadow, which doesn't help. Thanks.

```
shadow.alpha = 0.95;
shadow.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
shadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
shadow.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
shadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much ........ for this code helped me to make a shaddow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the UIImageView's layer to have the shadow, rather than having two views?

If that doesn't give the desired output, does a black UIView work? If you post a screenshot and the desired effect, maybe I can be of more assistance.

Comment: I took your advice, worked out the bugs, and got it to work that way. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do what you're attempting using the built-in shadow facilities. As you've discovered, there has to be something drawn in order for Quartz to have an outline to automatically shadow. (In this case, it's the background roundrect of the view.)

If you specify an explicit roundrect shadowPath for the shadow view's layer, that will do away with the need for the view to actually draw anything. However, the shadow itself appears to be constructed by filling the shadow path and then blurring and translating the resulting image, so you'll end up with essentially the same effect of a black background for the view.

I agree with Ryan Oksenhorn that you'd be better off working with the image view itself. If you add a shadow there, its opacity will drop with the view's, but that's probably all for the better. Do you really want to fade the image and leave a disembodied shadow behind?

Answer (score 0):

How about you set

```
shadow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.alpha = 1.0;
```